# HTML JavaScript Encoder and C# Decoder

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, encoding

I would like to implement HTML encoder in JavaScript like [this](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx). And implement the corresponding decoder like [this](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Decode.aspx).

Any encoder/decoder would work. Those were just examples.

My ultimate goal is to transfer HTML markup via a HiddenField and then use that transferred HTML on the destination. Without encoding/decoding, the page breaks. That's why I would like to encode in JavaScript and decode in C#.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? If you use the DOM and request properties correctly, you shouldn't actually need to do anything.

Comment: I tried to set the HTML markup to the HiddenField. But when there is <br /> and other tags. I page break:

Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: ASP.NET blocks HTML content in form fields as malicious content, and this is probably the error you are getting (the framework throws an exception).

Comment: I believe so. Isn't there a workaround?

Comment: @yazanpro: Read the server error in the Network tab.  If that is the problem, disable request validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript encoder:

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
     //create a in-memory div, set its inner text (which jQuery automatically encodes)
     //then grab the encoded contents back out. The div never exists on the page.
     return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

C# decoder:

```
public string HTMLDecode(value)
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
}
```